# Cronjob fetching JSON with cURL. Check if response isn't empty before writing to file

Tags: linux, cron, curl, json

I'm running Ubuntu and got a simple cronjob fetching a remote JSON-file and (over)writing it to the server.

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -m 120 -s https://path/to/remote/json.json > /store/json/here.json
```

However I need to make sure the external JSON actually returns data before it overwrites the JSON file located on the server.

How can I achieve this? I've found some ways to do it straight in bash, but doesn't seem to work when I put in the crontab.

Comment: create a script that would do it and use the script in crontab instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a short shell script and call the script from your crontab.

The script may look something like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

cd /store/json || exit 1

if curl -m 120 -s https://path/to/remote/json.json >here.json.tmp &&
    [ -s here.json.tmp ]
then
    mv here.json.tmp here.json
else
    rm here.json.tmp
fi
```

The `-s` test is *true* if the given file has a size greater than zero.

Comment: also consider using the return status from `curl`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: I was thinking of **using** the return status, to determining if it was successful. Why replace the file if not successful.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Ah, sure. I used `sh -e` in my first version, to terminate if anything failed. That would potentially have left the temporary file around I realise now. I'll rewrite it the way I think you mean.

Comment: Ahh. Yes terminate on error should do it.